# how to draw a triangular grid of length n in mathematica

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I am wondering if anyone could please help to draw a triangular grid (equilateral) with edge length n in mathematica. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**A Simple Grid:**

```
p = Table[ Table[

    Polygon[{j - 1/2 i, i Sqrt[3]/2} + # & /@ {{0, 0}, {1/2,Sqrt[3]/2}, {1, 0}}],

    {j, i, 9}], {i, 0, 9}];

Graphics[{EdgeForm[Black], FaceForm[White], p}]
```

[image: Triangular Grid]

**Edit**

A more clear version, I guess:

```
s3 = Sqrt[3];
templateTriangleVertex = {{0, 0}, {1, s3}, {2, 0}};

p = Table[Table[

    Polygon[{2 j - i, s3 i } + # & /@ templateTriangleVertex],

    {j, i, 9}], {i, 0, 9}];

Graphics[{EdgeForm[Black], FaceForm[White], p}]
```

Comment: thanks a lot. This is much simpler. But have you noticed that visually, this grid is not as "equilateral" as what Yaroslav has drawn. You know why and how to fix it?

Comment: @Qiang just remove the AspectRatio->1 (as it's just a display issue). I updated my answer

Comment: great! yours is so simple and therefore chosen as the answer to my question! thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Something like this?

[image]
<sub>(source: [yaroslavvb.com](http://yaroslavvb.com/upload/save/triangular-grid.png))</sub>

This is the code I used. Perhaps too complicated for the specific task above, it's part of code I had to visualize integer lattices like [this](http://yaroslavvb.com/upload/save/simplex.png)

```
A = Sqrt[2/3] {Cos[#], Sin[#], Sqrt[1/2]} & /@ 
    Table[Pi/2 + 2 Pi/3 + 2 k Pi/3, {k, 0, 2}] // Transpose;
p2r[{x_, y_, z_}] := Most[A.{x, y, z}];
n = 10;
types = 1/n Permutations /@ IntegerPartitions[n, {3}, Range[1, n]] // 
   Flatten[#, 1] &;
points = p2r /@ types;
Needs["ComputationalGeometry`"]
Graphics[{EdgeForm[Black], FaceForm[Transparent], 
  GraphicsComplex[points, 
   Polygon /@ DelaunayTriangulation[points // N][[All, 2]]]}]
```

What this does

1. types contains all 3 tuples of integers that add up to n. Those integers lie on a 2-dimensional subspace of R^3
2. A is a linear transformation to rotate those 3-tuples into x-y plane
3. Delauney triangulation finds all triangles connecting nearby points

Comment: looks great. Could you please explain a little bit the idea?

Answer (score 2):

Here is a variation on belisarius' method.

```
p = Table[{2 j - i, Sqrt[3] i}, {i, 0, 9}, {j, i, 9}]

Graphics[ Line @ Join[p, Riffle @@@ Partition[p, 2, 1]] ]
```

Comment: @belisarius by the way, do you favor the double Table form for clarity?

Comment: Starting your message with @user is useful only if the user have been participating in the comment thread for the answer or if he wrote the answer you're commenting on. If he didn't, he will not get alerted of your message, and probably will not read it at all. I got here just browsing past answers. Answering your question, sometimes _when it fits me_, I chose to write the code in the way I think it will be easier to understand for the OP (original poster), which is not always the way I'd write it for myself. Probably the most notable exception is when trying to solve performance problems.

Comment: Moreover, if you read the last of Qiang's comments in my answer, you'll see that many times simplicity is a real value for the OP. If I write a question, I'll value more a simple and easy to understand answer than one than takes me hours to understand ... unless I'm researching something and the answer gives me food for thought.

Comment: I will try to follow your advice.